# If $(T-I)^k=0$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ then $T\in\text{SL}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $T$ be a linear transformation such that 
$(T-I)^k=0$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then prove that $T\in\text{SL}(V)$.

Any ideas ?

Comment: To get the idea for $k=2$: $$0=(T-I)^2=T^2-2T+I,$$ hence $$T(2I-T)=I.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(T-I)^k=0$ implies that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is a divisor of $(x-1)^k$. This implies that the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $1$. This implies that the determinant of $T$ (which is the product of all eigenvalues) is $1$.

Comment: We are using the fact that minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial have the same roots (possibly with different multiplicities). Am I right ?

Comment: well, you can proof "roots of min-poly = eigenvalues" without using characteristic polynomials at all.

Answer (score 1):

We don't even need that $V$ is finite-dimensional. 
Let $\displaystyle S := \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}(I-T)^n$. Then $\displaystyle TS = (I-(I-T))S = S - (I-T)S = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}(I-T)^n-\sum_{n=1}^k(I-T)^n = (I-T)^0 - (I-T)^k = I$.

Similarly we get $ST = I$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $k = 2$ the equation is $0 = (T - I)^2 = T^2 - 2T + I = T(T - 2I) + I$, i.e. $T(2I - T) = I$.